# Defer based on recipient with exim

Tags: acl, exim

There are some recipient domains which have problematic delivery which is keeping the server tied up.

Is there a way I can match certain recipient domains and defer/freeze messages to a given list of domain? Maybe with an ACL?

This would of course need to happen before the attempted relay to be effective in saving any time.